# Should you use past tense for a fact that still remains in force?

Tags: grammar

For example what variant is correct?

- He was the man who did that first.
- He is the man who did that first.
- He himself appeared in a film about his life.
- He himself appears in a film about his life.
- He was the strongest man ever when he was alive.
- He is still the strongest man ever even though he is dead.
- He said this in his letters.
- He says this in his letters.
- In this photo he looked healthy.
- In this photo he looks healthy.

Comment: You used the wrong preposition in "On this photo...." That wasn't the point of your question, so I've corrected it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of your sentences, past and present tense are both fine.  E.g.:

> He said this in his letters.

This is fine, because he wrote the letter in the past.

> He says this in his letters.

Even though he died 100 years ago, he still speaks through his letters, so this is also fine.

Be careful with this one:

> He himself appeared in a film about his life.

This is okay, but only because the verb *appear* can mean *to take part in a film/movie, play, television programme, etc*.

The only one I consider wrong is:

> * In this photo he looked healthy.

If you want to use the past tense, you should use *appear*.

When you say *he looks healthy* the focus is on you, and your experience.  Your experience is happening now, so use the present tense.

When you say *he appears / appeared healthy* the focus is on him.  He appeared healthy at the time the photo was taken and, because the photo has not changed, he still appears healthy now.

> In this photo he *looks* healthy.  `OK`
>
> In this photo he *appears* healthy.  `OK`
>
> In this photo he *looked* healthy.  `WRONG`
>
> In this photo he *appeared* healthy.  `OK`

**EDIT**

Barrie England points out that, in certain contexts, “In this photo he looked healthy.” is fine. The sense is something like, “As you can see in this photo, he looked healthy in 2000.”

Comment: You suggest "past and present tense are both fine" in most examples, apparently extending this approval to counterfactual "He is still the strongest man ever even though he is dead."

Comment: @jwpat7 The keyword is *ever*.  *Ever* implies we are looking back through all of history, i.e., “He is the strongest man who ever lived.”  If I say, “He **was** the strongest man ever.” then I do not exclude the possibility of even stronger men who came later.

Answer (score 2):

All of your examples are grammatical. The choice between present and past tense in such cases depends to a large extent on how the speaker views the action or event described, and on the surrounding text. To take your last pair as representative, the comment *In this photo he looked healthy* might precede a further comment that he later contracted a fatal disease. *In this photo he looks healthy* carries less of an implication that his health subsequently deteriorated. These are subtle differences and the use of one or the other cannot be divorced from the situation in which each might occur.

Comment: Barrie's last sentence is the key point. Any given utterance is set in a context, which will determine the choice of tense. For example, in the context of a biography on the life of Churchill, it would be natural to use the past tense: *He said this in his letters.* Other the other hand, in the context of someone now trying to extrapolate Churchill's character from comments he made in his letters, the present tense may seem more natural to the speaker.

Answer (score -3):

According to English grammar universal truths and facts are always Present tense. As in "Sun sets in west". FYI http://www.englishtenses.com/tenses/present_simple

Comment: I ate breakfast today.  That's a fact.  Which tense did I use?

Comment: Not everything is a 'universal truth'. Not down voting, though.

Comment: @Kris Apoorva edited their answer after I downvoted it.  It’s more accurate, not, but doesn’t really answer the question, so I’m leaving the downvote as it is.

Comment: Sure. No reason why you should change it now.

Comment: @Pitarou i understand :) you need not give a justification. I edited it mainly because, i had missed out the word "Universal" in my answer. And i also realized that the question is not regarding "Universal facts" but just "facts" .

Answer (score -4):

- He was the man who did that first. — OK
- He is the man who did that first. — OK
- He himself appeared in a film about his life. — OK
- He himself appears in a film about his life. — OK
- He was the strongest man ever when he was alive. — OK
- He is still the strongest man ever even though he is dead. — WRONG
- He said this in his letters. — OK
- He says this in his letters. — OK
- In this photo he looked healthy. — WRONG, but "In this photo he appeared healthy" is OK
- In this photo he looks healthy. — OK

Comment: The first sentence you identify as incorrect is valid in certain contexts. It could, at least in speech, be considered a valid contraction of, "He is still _the holder of the title_ 'strongest man ever' even though he is dead." The ever implies 'for all time' and so is not limited by such puny constraints as mortality!